# Spark Read csv with missing quotes

Tags: apache-spark

spark.read

```
val data = spark.read
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .quote("quote", "\"")
      .csv("file:///opt/spark/test1.tsv")
```

incorrectly interprets lines with missing quotes, even though tab delimeter exists
for example line:

```
"aaa" \t "b'bb \t 222
```

is interpreted as `` "aaa", "b`bb 222" `` 
instead of

`` "aaa", "b`bb", "222" ``

according to the documentation deli-meters inside quotes are ignored.
I can get around the problem by re defining default quote for example:
`.option("quote","+")` 
but it's not a good solution

Comment: and how would spark know that it should put an extra `"` at the end of bb, or not to include `"` inside the first and second elements? it seems more of a wrongly formatted file, rather than a parsing problem. The purpose of using quotes, is exactly to avoid splitting a delimiter inside a quoted value. Did you try not using quote option? One solution would be to just split by `\t` and then remove quotes (if needed)

Comment: you can't just split by \t because it's using a default for quote ("\"") . so it seems that quote is taking priority over splitting

Comment: I see. Then can you change the default quote to something else?

Comment: I did that ```option("quote","^"), but i don't like the solution

Comment: is this a `"b'bb` copy/paste mistake. quote are not closed.

Comment: that's the point quote is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if quotes are not closing properly, the only option is to keep it when creating dataframe and later on drop it using custom logic.

```
scala> spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").option("quote", "").csv("test.csv").show()
+-----+-----+---+
|  _c0|  _c1|_c2|
+-----+-----+---+
|"aaa"|"b'bb| 22|
+-----+-----+---+
```

Now if you know which column, might have an issue just apply the following logic.

```
scala> df.withColumn("col_without_quotes", regexp_replace($"_c0","\"","")).show()
+-----+-----+---+------------------+
|  _c0|  _c1|_c2|col_without_quotes|
+-----+-----+---+------------------+
|"aaa"|"b'bb| 22|               aaa|
+-----+-----+---+------------------+
```